# Consolidating duplicate data in a large table based on an ID (excel & xml)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel document with A LOT of info that came from an xml file.

At the moment when I open the XML file I get something like this.

```
| ID | Name  | action | trait  | stats |
|----|-------|--------|--------|-------|
| 1  | bob   | move   | strong | high  |
| 1  | bob   |        | fast   |       |
| 2  | annie | punch  | tall   | low   |
```

What I need in the long run is this.

```
| ID | Name  | action | trait  | trait2 | stats |
|----|-------|--------|--------|--------|-------|
| 1  | bob   | move   | strong |  fast  |  high |
| 2  | annie | punch  | tall   |        |  low  |
```

Is there anyway to make this happen?

This is an oversimplification of the document I'm working with.

The main reason I need this is I have a front page that lets you pick a name from a drop down a menu. After you pick from the drop down menu the rest of the information is auto populated. If I have two rows with the same ID/Name, then the dropdown has multiple duplicates that can't be selected, and the extra traits or actions never get populated.

Maybe there is a better way to make my 'reference calls' or deal with this whole problem. The way I know excel would be to have everything on one column so I'm asking for a solution at the moment based on that. I welcome better ways of doing things though.

EDIT: More info in case it helps. The actions and traits also have their own IDs. unfortunately their aren't unique to the first ID. If there was a way to make that happen that could also solve my problem. ie: Action ids just increment all the way. 1-100. If they were 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, and so that that would make it easier too.

Example of the IDs and the nightmare they are causing.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GW3VVswjpUgZNnTg_OJQo_paK5q-Xa332_6CmUQikTM/edit?usp=sharing